# codesign still tries to access other keychains when adding --keychain parameter

Tags: keychain, code-signing

we have a automated codesigning setup on our CI/CD infrastructure which is using the codesing command to resign a iOS application with a certificate located in a specific keychain. The codesign script works in general but I detected an unexpected behavior. Even though I tell the codesign command with '--keychain' the keychain it should use, it still tries to access the keychains from the keychain search list. If I add all keychains to the searchlist it will lock the execution on a certain call because it tries to access a password protected keychain which is in the search list. If I remove all keychains from the search list (except the login and the system keychain), codesign won't find the proper signing identity even when pointing to the proper keychain with the --keychain argument.

the codesign command is called as follows:

```
codesign --sign <signidentity> ---keychain <path/to/my.keychain> --force
```

This one happens on macOS 10.14.4 and 10.13.6. I also tried different xcode versions like 9.2.1, 9.4.x and 10.1.

I'm a little bit at the end of my ideas of how to solve this issue. It feels that the --keychain argument is bugged or doesn't do what I think it should do.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem. For now, we have to add the keychain we want to the search list as the only keychain. Then restore all keychains after codesign.